# select only one row from multiple rows MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a `orders` table as follows:

```
id | cust_id| status
1     25         1
2     25         1
3     25         0
4     26         0
5     26         1
6     26         0
7     27         1
8     27         1
9     27         1
```

I need two queries:

**1. fetch all the 'cust_id' having at least one status 0.**

*eg. in above table I should get cust_id with two rows 25 and 26 because they have at least one 0 in 'status' column.*

**2. fetch all the 'cust_id' having all status 1.**

*eg. in above table I should get cust_id with one row 27 because it has all 1's in the 'status' column.*

Comment: can you please share you query you try....???

Comment: I have made one query for first condition which I think is correct.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `orders` where status=0 group by cust_id

Comment: i think it will work for your second condtion also did you try. select * from orders where status = 1 group by cust_id

Comment: For question 1, can you please provide the query which you tried before posting?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming status is numeric

```
select distinct cust_id 
from my_table where status  = 0 


select disctint cust_id
from my_table  
where cust_id NOT in (select distinct cust_id 
from my_table where status  = 0 )
```

these are the two queries  ..

if you need  both result in same select you can use union

```
select distinct cust_id 
from my_table where status  = 0 
union 
select disctint cust_id
from my_table  
where cust_id NOT in (select distinct cust_id 
from my_table where status  = 0 )
```

Comment: scaisEdge gets top marks for completing their homework assignment

Comment: I think there are not Firts Class  question and Second class Question  .. a question is a question .. also if is an homework .. of someone else

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust_id FROM orders WHERE status=0
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT cust_id FROM orders WHERE status=1 
AND cust_id NOT IN (SELECT cust_id FROM orders WHERE status<>1)
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more details, rather than just the SQL statement. Thanks.